# Download source from npm without installing it

Tags: node.js, package, npm

How can I download the source code of a package from npm without actually installing it (i.e. without using `npm install thepackage`)?

Answer (score 131):

You can use `npm view [package name] dist.tarball` which will return the URL of the compressed package file.

Here's an example using `wget` to download the tarball:

```
wget $(npm view lodash dist.tarball)
```

Comment: `npm pack <package's name>` is the shortest current way

Comment: Downvoted because this doesn't use npm authentication information and results in 401 errors for private packages.

Comment: Caret-ish versions like `jquery@2` result in multiple URLs being returned

Comment: @revelt you just need your `.npmrc` adjusted for the scope and that's it.

Answer (score 115):

A simpler way to do this is `npm pack <package_name>`. This will retrieve the tarball from the registry, place it in your npm cache, and put a copy in the current working directory. See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/pack

Comment: Perfect. Also: `npm pack --dry-run <package_name>` will produce the same exact output, without placing the `tgz` file in the current directory.

Answer (score 88):

**If you haven't installed npm**, with the current public API, you can also access the information about a package in the npm registry from the URL `https://registry.npmjs.org/<package-name>/`.

Then you can navigate the JSON at `versions > (version number) > dist > tarball` to get the URL of the code archive and download it.

Comment: you can use `latest` as version number (e.g. `https://registry.npmjs.org/pm2-logrotate/latest`) then find `dist.tarball`. even use a one-liner on *nix systems: `curl -sS https://registry.npmjs.org/pm2-logrotate/latest | jq -r .dist.tarball`

Answer (score 40):

`npm pack XXX` is the quickest to type and it'll download an archive.

Alternatively:

```
npm v XXX dist.tarball | xargs curl | tar -xz
```

this command will also:

- Download the package with progress bar
- Extracts into a folder called `package`

Comment: Additionally, if you want to keep the same filename as the registry you could skip the last pipe as in: `npm v XXX dist.tarball | xargs curl -O`. In this case, curl -O will keep the filename from the npm registry, and since the file is already a tar.gz there's no need to pipe it again through the tar command.

Answer (score 23):

On linux I usually download the tarball of a package like this:

```
wget `npm v [package-name] dist.tarball`
```

Notice the backticks ``, on stackoverflow I cannot see them clearly.

"v" is just another alias for view:

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view

Comment: This command gives you the direct link to the tarball.
https://registry.npmjs.org/packagename/-/packagename-version.tgz

Comment: Do  not use backticks anymore. Use the POSIX syntax instead: `$()`.

Answer (score 7):

You can also access the content of a npm package online:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react?activeTab=code
- https://unpkg.com/browse/react/ (the trailing slash is required)

Answer (score 4):

For simply viewing the overview of the contents of an npm package, without downloading anything locally, you can use:

```sh
npm pack --dry-run <package-name>
```

**Demo:**

```
$ npm pack --dry-run express
npm notice
npm notice   express@4.17.2
npm notice === Tarball Contents ===
npm notice 110.6kB History.md
npm notice 1.2kB   LICENSE
npm notice 4.8kB   Readme.md
npm notice 224B    index.js
npm notice 14.3kB  lib/application.js
npm notice 2.4kB   lib/express.js
npm notice 853B    lib/middleware/init.js
npm notice 885B    lib/middleware/query.js
npm notice 12.5kB  lib/request.js
npm notice 27.3kB  lib/response.js
npm notice 15.0kB  lib/router/index.js
npm notice 3.3kB   lib/router/layer.js
npm notice 4.1kB   lib/router/route.js
npm notice 5.9kB   lib/utils.js
npm notice 3.3kB   lib/view.js
npm notice 2.8kB   package.json
npm notice === Tarball Details ===
npm notice name:          express
npm notice version:       4.17.2
npm notice filename:      express-4.17.2.tgz
npm notice package size:  54.7 kB
npm notice unpacked size: 209.6 kB
npm notice shasum:        c18369f265297319beed4e5558753cc8c1364cb3
npm notice integrity:     sha512-oxlxJxcQlYwqP[...]66Ha8jCUo9QGg==
npm notice total files:   16
npm notice
express-4.17.2.tgz
```

Answer (score 1):

My team created [OSS Gadget](https://github.com/Microsoft/OSSGadget) to make things like this easier, especially when working across different ecosystems. One of the tools in this suite is called `oss-download`:

```
oss-download pkg:npm/express         # Latest version
oss-download pkg:npm/express@4.17.1  # Specific version
oss-download pkg:npm/express@*       # All versions
oss-download -e pkg:npm/express      # Decompress contents recursively
```

If you're only interested in npm, then `npm pack` is your best option, but if you don't have npm installed or need to do similar things with PyPI, RubyGems, NuGet, etc., then OSS Gadget might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Gustavo Rodrigues's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27929112), fixes "package" directory in .tgz, adds latest minor version discovery.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]] ; then
    echo "Usage: $0 jquery bootstrap@3 tinymce@4.5"
    exit 64 ## EX_USAGE
fi

set -e ## So nothing gets deleted if download fails

for pkg_name in "$@"
do

    ## Get latest version, also works with plain name
    url=$( npm v $pkg_name dist.tarball | tail -n 1 | cut -d \' -f 2 )
    tmp_dir=$( mktemp -d -p . "${pkg_name}__XXXXXXXXX" )

    ## Unpacks to directory named after package@version
    curl $url | tar -xzf - --strip 1 --directory $tmp_dir
    rm -rf $pkg_name
    mv $tmp_dir $pkg_name
done
```