# Download node module sources without installing them?

Tags: node.js, package.json

I would like to download node module packages (listed in a package.json file, in the present working directory) source code to a node_modules subdirectory of the present working directory, without compiling, or installing those modules. Now I have seen the related question [download source from npm without npm install xxx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035786/download-source-from-npm-without-npm-install-xxx) but that question dealt with downloading the source code of individual modules specified to NPM directly (i.e., without using a package.json file). The reason why I want to do this is because I am working on developing an Atom package for the Open Build Service (OBS) of openSUSE and this seems like one of the necessary steps I need to go through in order to achieve this.

Comment: `npm install --ignore-scripts`?

Answer (score 0):

The source code is not shipped with the npm distributed code. The best you could do is read the package.json and look for the `{ repository: url { } }` key if it exists and if it's a git repo (which most of them will be) clone it.

However be aware that the source code often requires a build step before it can be used, as in an npm `prepublish` step defined in the source code. In modern Javascript projects a common example of this is transpiling ES6 code to ES5 code for use in NodeJS and the browser.

I have not made an Atom package but I'm fairly certain you don't need to do any of this.