# Using rsocket-js client without Node.js

Tags: javascript, rsocket

I'm looking at the documentation https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-js/blob/master/docs/01-client-configuration.md

However I find something is missing, where do you actually get the `rsocket-core` and `rsocket-websocket-client` without firing up node js? I mean using `rsocket-websocket-client` in pure browser?

Comment: What do you mean, where to actually get it? If it's about installing it, then check the README: https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-js. There are npm pacakges listed for installing. Otherwise the documentation link you linked in your question starts with a section how to use it in the browser...

Comment: @AndreiBoyanov I think what this means is not using Node.js, e.g npm, the project must have no `package.json` and is a pure browser based setup

Comment: You could just download the npm package and then use browserify.

Comment: if you mean to avoid installing npm to get the packages, I think this thread is useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035786/download-source-from-npm-without-installing-it

Comment: i have the same question as yours. how to use rsocket-js in html and javascript only? for example: use httpd to serve html, js and connect to another java spring rsocket websocket server.