# How to Use NPM packages in vanilla JS without HTML file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I want to use **NPM** package in my `index.js` file without installing it with package manager, i don't have a **HTML** file, i only have `index.js` file which is executed with `node index.js` command when i have to use this file anywhere, so i can't use **CDN**. Is there any way i can use the package in my js file without installing it and without using **CDN**. Or is there any way we can require or import a package locally in js file.

Comment: [`crypto` is a node core module](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html).

Comment: Why are you not willing to use NPM?  What objective are you trying to accomplish?  The feels like an XY question that doesn't really explain the real objective/problem here.  You can copy modules from NPM and just include them in your own source.  Not sure why you'd do that since you orphan that code from future bug fixes and improvements, but you can.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in `require` function to import all node.js modules.

```js
const crypto = require("node:crypto");
```

Comment: What about other packages

Comment: Install them (using npm) and then also import/require them.

Comment: as i already said in the question, i Dont want to install them using nom

Comment: @NasyxNadeem then you'll be stuck to using the default packages. There's no work-around for that.

Comment: although, you could use something like vite to compile your modules if you don't want to ship them to production.

Answer (score 1):

This package crypto is no longer supported and has been deprecated. To avoid malicious use, npm is hanging on to the package name.

It's now a built-in Node module. If you've depended on crypto, you should switch to the one that's built-in.

you can use it by : `const crypto = require("crypto");`

Comment: What if i have to use any other package

Comment: check out this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035786/download-source-from-npm-without-installing-it#:~:text=If%20you%20haven't%20installed,code%20archive%20and%20download%20it.